# Android Studio - Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm really new to Android Studio,

I'm facing some problem of Asynchronous Task to download multiple of images from my database through PHP.
For example, I would like to download 50 images from database and I started the AsyncTask, however in the middle (let say image 38th), internet connection disconnected, seconds later, internet connection connected back. How am i gonna to tell my apps to start download image 38th till 50th? Is there anyway of doing this?
i'm using ListView & BaseAdapter to show my images.

Please help~

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Picasso Library

http://square.github.io/picasso/

It works like this :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

It works with a cache, so images that have already been loaded won't be downloaded twice

Comment: Hi Dany, thanks for your reply,

just saying that, if i were willing to use other's coding / github / library etc, i would have done that. i love to seek and look deep into the concept/coding etc. i'm not just "get work done" only. i wish to understand more.